# How do you make a 3d geometry of a real world object in three js?

Tags: 3d, three.js

I have a client who makes plastic bottles just like this:

[plastic bottles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLAmN.jpg)

They have a requirement to show these bottles on a web page in a shopping style site. When you get to a particualr bottle, you should be able to view it in 3D and rotate it. I don't know anything about 3d but three.js seemed like it might do it.

However, I need to be able to turn the bottle into a three.js geometry. How does one do this as it is an irregular shape? Do I have to model it in some other software first? How do I capture this geometry somehow?

Comment: Ask the client for a file of the bottle in a 3D format ... once you have the model file its very easy to use Three.js to render online

Comment: What's a valid 3D format that three.js could make sense of?

Comment: With a modelling software such as blender.

Comment: You can model the bottle or download a model of a bottle and use the threejs exporter addon for blender, both are free. Then use the json loader to import this model into blender

Answer (score 0):

You need to build 3d model in some other program like [Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/) or so (if you want it free and legal) end export it in some format or compact it in a js file.
Than build scene and use some of the three [loaders](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=loader) like OBJLoader.js (and probabli MTLLoader.js) for the model and the texture.